# Add dynamic content in ArrayList of String in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create a content management system in Java, where I insert chapter names and create sections inside a chapter. I have used the following data structures:

```
static ArrayList<String> chapters = new ArrayList<String>();
static Map<String,ArrayList<String>> subsections = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

Now, for insertion, I am using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> secname = new ArrayList<String>();
secname.add(textField.getText());
MyClass.subsections.put("Chapter", secname);
```

The problem is I am getting the last element, the rest of the elements are getting overwritten. But, I cannot use a fixed ArrayList for the chapters. I have to insert strings runtime and from the GUI. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Are you using `Chapter` for all the keys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you create a new *empty* arraylist every time. You need to retrieve the existing one, if any, and add to it. Something like:

```
List<String> list = MyClass.subsections.get("Chapter");
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String> ();
    MyClass.subsections.put("Chapter", list);
}
list.add(textField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the ArrayList containing the subsections from the map first:

```
ArrayList<String> section = subsections.get("Chapter");
```

Then create it only if it doesn't exist:

```
if (section == null) {
    ArrayList<String> section = new ArrayList<String>();
    subsections.put("Chapter", section);
}
```

Then append your text at the end of the section:

```
section.add(textField.getText());
```

Your code does replace the ArrayList at index "Chapter" every time you call "put", potentially removing the previous saved data at this index.